# How to show list of items when click on button in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

i placed one button in a page .when click on that need to show 1 to 30 numbers in combobox as a popup in that page only.please tell me how to acheive this?

Edit:

[image: see the image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited the answer with design,add an image as a local content in the project

```
  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button Content="Button" Height="82" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,59,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="376" Click="button1_Click" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding item}" Width="376" Name="lst" Margin="56,128,48,76" Background="White">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" DataContext="{Binding}"  BorderBrush="Black">
                        <StackPanel Width="376" Orientation="Vertical" Height="Auto">
                            <Image Margin="200,20,-75,5"  Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding img}"></Image>
                            <TextBlock Margin="-200,-15,90,3"  Height="50" Width="50" Name="text" Text="{Binding text}" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

 lst.visibility = visibility.collapsed;

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        lst.visibility = visibility.visible;
        List<Itemss> data = new List<Itemss>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
        Itemss item = new Itemss();


            item.text = i.ToString();



            item.img = "/images.jpg";

            data.Add(item);

        }

        lst.ItemsSource = data;
       }



    public class Itemss
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string img { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Comment: By using listpicker i can't get.when click on a button need to show 1 to 30 numbers .by using listpicker i need to click on that then only showing all items.please tell me which control is suitable when click on button need to show 1 to 30 numbers in same page ..

Comment: try to set the visibility to collapsed before the button click and when click make it to visible. I cant understand your question and can you show an image example to know what you actually needed.

Comment: Try a list box for this. I have edited the answer if any further doubts kindly ask me

Comment: Can you please tell me like that above i have to design the listbox elements.as of now elements are showing in listbox.design is not good..only showing 1 to 30 numbers in listbox but how to design like the above screenshot..

Comment: i added the listbox with design which matches your requirement.

Comment: Thanks @SENTHAL ..Can we place header like "Please select radius" in listbox......

Comment: Please tell me how do you set the margins exactly for listbox?by using expression blend you are desgning the listbox or how to set the margins...?

Comment: if you go for the term header you should use long list selector. just change the button content to select radius.I set it manually i dont have any experience of using expression blend

Answer (score 1):

YOu can make use of the [ListPicker for WP7](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth) instead of a ComboBox for WP7.

And to show the ListPicker in a popup, Place the ListPicker in a [MessagePrompt](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Coding4Fun-WP7-Message-Prompt-in-depth).

Comment: By using listpicker again i need to click on that control to show all items.but i need to show the items when click on a button placed in same page...which control i need to use to show the items when click on button in same page?

Comment: Then use a MessagePrompt with a ListBox placed inside it. And you can set the source of the listbox with 1 to 30 no's

Comment: [How to create MessagePrompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessagePrompt&referringTitle=Documentation) and [How to create and use ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.95).aspx)